# Problemas com Stored Procedures no Laravel 5.6?

Tags: sql, laravel-5, stored-procedures

Estou fazendo um `select` em uma `procedure`, porem não consigo ***paginar*** pois o resultado retorna `array`:

```
DB::select('EXEC PR_MONITORAMENTO @FUNCAO="S2", @ID_CD_INTERNACAO='.$ID_INTERNACAO.', 
     @ID_CD_CONVENIO='.$ID_CONVENIO.',@NM_PESSOA= '.$NM_PESSOA.'');
```

E quando faço um db::raw ele retorna um objeto com o nome

```
DB::raw('EXEC PR_MONITORAMENTO @FUNCAO="S2", @ID_CD_INTERNACAO='.$ID_INTERNACAO.', 
     @ID_CD_CONVENIO='.$ID_CONVENIO.',@NM_PESSOA= '.$NM_PESSOA.'');
```

---

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression)#290 (1) 
{ 
    ["value":protected]=> string(95) 
    "EXEC PR_MONITORAMENTO @FUNCAO="S2", @ID_CD_INTERNACAO=, 
        @ID_CD_CONVENIO=,@NM_PESSOA= " 
}
```

Eu quero fazer o `select` nessa `procedure` e **paginar**, alguma dica?

Comment: Você tem que paginar a sua `Stored Procedure` e com `DB::select` realmente não vai dar certo, porque a sua lógica está na `Stored Procedure`. Agora se fosse uma Visão (`View`) dava para fazer o que precisa!

Comment: No caso eu teria que fazer esse select da stored procedure dentro da view certo? mas isso fugiria das boas praticas? agradeço desde ja

Comment: No caso você deveria fazer somente a `View` !!!